# OpenLayers WMTS layers are shifted to south/east

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers v6.3.1 to render a WMTS layers of Austria's countries ('Burgenland' in the east and 'Tirol' in the west). Here is a code sandbox I created to show the code and the options used: https://codesandbox.io/s/wmts-openlayers-bgld-x7lcy

The problem is that the tiles are rendered way too much south/east (Turkey/Izmir) instead of Austria/Burgenland and Macedonia/Greek instead of Austria/Tirol:

[image]

I'm sure both the data of the layer and the proj4 definitions are correct because it get's rendered in QGIS correctly:

[image: Macedonia/]

Why does this happen?

### Edit

As @Mike pointed out QGIS seems to detect the inconsistency and apply a workaround for it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the capabilities document the coordinates are in north-east order even though the projections are all east-north (if I define it as north-east the layers appear in a different wrong place with the text facing sideways).  Go get around that I defined the projections as north-east and copies of the projections as east-north then changed the projection in the options after parsing.  There is also a bug in OpenLayers which is fixed in the latest development version so you will need to use that until thee is another official release.  https://codesandbox.io/s/wmts-openlayers-bgld-qmxhu

For comparison here a ***real*** north-east projection where no workaround is needed https://codesandbox.io/s/wmts-axis-neu-d2vux

Comment: Your workaround works quite well, thanks. I've two questions:

1) how can I decide if I should add the NE postfix?
2) can you please point me to the OpenLayers issue that fixes (?) the problem

Thanks, Thomas

Comment: Is this related to https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/10981?

Comment: The problem with version 6.3.1 is related to that, but unlike the Polish service your WMTS doesn't work correctly with earlier versions (6.2.1) of OpenLayers even with the workaround.  I don't think there is any way to detect NE coordinates being used with what is usually an EN projection apart from looking for inconsistencies - in this case the TopLeftCorner of the TileMatrix would be below the LowerCorner of the BoundingBox in EN coordinates.  Maybe that is how QGIS does it?

Comment: There also appears to be a bug in proj4js version 2.6.1 influencing this.  If I use version 2.6.0 the projections only need to be defined as NE, there is no need for a subsequent EN workaround https://codesandbox.io/s/wmts-openlayers-bgld-bwyb3